# Java 1.6 - Return to the Main class from an executor service thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I'm executing three tasks from my Main class by creating 3 threads (extends Runnable) using the Executor Service and submitting them. Like below:

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors
                        .newFixedThreadPool(3);

                A a= new A();
                B b= new B();
                C c= new C();

                /**
                 * Submit/Execute the jobs
                 */
                executor.execute(a);
                executor.execute(b);
                executor.execute(c);
                try {
                    latch.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //handle - show info
                    executor.shutdownNow();
                }
```

When an exception occurs in the thread, I catch it and do System.exit(-1). But, I need to return to the main class if any exception occurs and execute some statements there. How to do this? Can we return something from these threads without FutureTask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of submitting the task via `execute` which does not give you any capability of catching exception outside the `run` methods, use `submit` which returns a `Future<?>`. You can then call `get` which may return an `ExecutionException` if something went wrong:

```
Future<?> fa = executor.submit(a);
try {
    fa.get();  // wait on the future
} catch(ExecutionException e) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong: " + e.getCause());
    // do something specific
}
```

Comment: You might add that `Runnable`s may wrap catched checked exceptions into an instance of a subclass of `RuntimeException` in order to rethrow…

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own "FutureTask" class and give it as an argument to A's constructor:

```
MyFutureTask futureA = new MyFutureTask();
A a = new A(futureA);
```

Whenever an error happens in A you store the return value in your MyFutureTask and can then read it as your would with a normal FutureTask.